# How to use arrows to show the movement of a decimal point when multiplying a number and a power of 10?

Tags: math-mode, macros, arrows

I am trying to produce the arrow(s) that point from the original position of the decimal point to its final location when multiplying or dividing a number by a power of ten.

For example, if you have `0.05 * 100 = 5`, how do you show this?

[image: Five hundredths going to 5]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please read the [introductory material](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) for this site. When you post a question, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see if the following works for you:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning, tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\huge
$0\tikzmark{A}.\tikzmark{B}0\tikzmark{C}0\tikzmark{D}$

\normalsize
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture,
node distance = 0pt
                        ]
\coordinate[below=of $(pic cs:A)!0.5!(pic cs:B)$]  (a);
%
\draw[-latex,shorten <=3pt]
    (a)         to [out=270, in=270,looseness=4] (pic cs:C)
    (pic cs:C)  to [out=270, in=270,looseness=5] (pic cs:D);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

to better see result, the math expression has increased font size:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I figured out another solution with a custom command that attach the symbol `\acwunderarcarrow` from `stix` package to the bottom of the numeral.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{stix}
    
\newcommand{\dposr}[1]{%
  \kern-0.9ex\mathop{%
  \acwunderarcarrow}\limits^{\vbox to -.1ex{%
    \kern -1.4ex\hbox{#1}}
  }
}
\newcommand{\ShowDecPos}[2]{%
  {#1\kern.8ex}\raisebox{-1.4ex}{$\kern-.2ex\dposr#2$}
}

\begin{document}

$0.9\times10^{1}=\ShowDecPos{0.}{9}=9$

\bigskip

$0.005\times10^{3}=\ShowDecPos{0.}{0}\ShowDecPos{}{0}\ShowDecPos{}{5}=5$

\bigskip

$0.00071\times10^{4}=\ShowDecPos{0.}{0}\ShowDecPos{}{0}\ShowDecPos{}{0}\ShowDecPos{}{7}1=7.1$

\end{document}
```

---

### UPDATE

### Improved code. Additional color.

Here is a simpler solution with just one custom command (and some color). Now the arrows are nearer to the numbers and the command depends just in one argument.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand\deci[1]{%
    \kern-.4ex\stackunder[0.4pt]{$#1$}{$\color{blue}\acwunderarcarrow$}
}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{l}
0.9\times10^{1}=0.\deci{9}=9 \\[3ex]
0.005\times10^{3}=0.\deci{0}\deci{0}\deci{5}=5 \\[3ex]
0.00071\times10^{4}=0.\deci{0}\deci{0}\deci{0}\deci{7}1=7.1
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

### Decimal position to left

Also I propose the code for the other direction that I achieved by using `reflectbox` in command

```
\newcommand\decposl[1]{%    <--- Decimal position to left
    \kern-.4ex\stackunder[0.4pt]{$#1$}{%
      \reflectbox{$\color{blue}\kern-.6ex\acwunderarcarrow$}
      }
}
```

Here, some examples

[image]

```
\[
\times10^{-4}=0.\underbrace{\decposl{0}\decposl{0}\decposl{0}\decposl{2}}_{4 \text{ places}}=0.0002
\]

\[
7.3\times 10^{-3}=0.\decposl{0}\decposl{0}\decposl{7}3=0.0073
\]
```

Comment: Your code to the other direction did not work for me (arrows still stay to the right side). I am not familiar with Latex, so it is not easy for me to understand where to put parts of code. Can you please write the other direction code fully ?